# What does と言わんばかりの mean here?

Tags: grammar

I checked out the other と言わんばかり stuff here, but I don't understand this still.

[image: Context]

The translation I have is:
**"Wide step, and slower steps than at competitions.
Both are movements that push you to the edge of losing your balance."**

I understand
どっちも = both
バランスを崩す = losing your balance
と言わんばかりに = as if to say

Not sure about what ぎりぎりの動き means (probably that it's a risky movement ?), but what does this last part literally mean? 
Thanks!

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%82%93%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A